# How to retrieve information from Pubmed according to date and term using Python?

Tags: python, biopython, pubmed

Can you tell me how I can obtain the 5 newest articles from [PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/) that contain the word 'obesity' and return the authors, the title, the date, doi and PubMed PMID of each paper using Python? Thank you in advance

EDIT:

My try so far. I believe this is the wanted result but i need to obtain the correct pubmed ids in order to run the function

```
from Bio.Entrez import efetch
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = 'name@example.com'

def print_abstract(pmid):
    handle = efetch(db='pubmed', id=pmid, retmode='text', rettype='abstract')
    print(handle.read())

print_abstract(pmid)
```

Comment: we can tell you, but it wont teach you anything.  We would need a LINK to the website and your attempt.

Comment: @Fallenreaper I believe this function may work just fine if i mange to get the correct ids according to date and term. Of course, there can be a better way that i haven't thought of yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`esearch`](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/#chapter4.ESearch) function from `Bio.Entrez` to find the UIDs of the most recent PubMed entries matching a query:

```
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term="obesity", retmax=5)
results = Entrez.read(handle)                                                   
print(results["IdList"])
```

By specifying `term`, you can provide a query string - from your question, you're looking for entries related to "obesity". `retmax` allows us to configure how many UIDs should be returned (default is 20).

When I run this now, I get the following UIDs:

```
['32171135', '32171042', '32170999', '32170940', '32170929']
```

At the time of writing, these correspond to the most recent entry UIDs when you perform the PubMed search manually. They are sorted with the most recent entry first.

Using these UIDs, your `print_abstract` function performs as expected.